# Auto populate Access 2010 Form with an entry from different field in last row

Tags: forms, vba

I'm making an access 2010 form that is going to be used as the front end to populate a flat table within the same database.
The Access form has "From" and "To" fields.  When the user fills out the entry and clicks forward to a new row (Fresh form) - I'd like for the "From" field in the fresh form to auto populate with the last entry's "To" field.
So to clarify I'd like to know how to make a procedure so that when a user is filling out a form using it as the front end to populate a flat table - the "From" field in a new row will automatically populate with the "To" from the last row.  These are From, To measurements thus From: 0.00 meter To:1.00 meter in the first row will become From: (Autopopulated with last "To" field) with the new "To" field blank for manual entry.
I'm very new to VBA etc. so if you could specify what something is, "Table", "Field" vs. using examples where I may not know the equivalent in my particular case that would be much appreciated.

Thank you kindly

UPDATE:

Hi Mark! I'm so amazed that this community exists. I really appreciate you taking the time to assist me. I'm afraid in order for me to get this you will have to dumb it down a bit more. I've never taken any training on this at all.

What I tried is clicking the FROM text field in design view. I went to event and in the "after update" field I clicked the ... then selected Code Builder. In the code I entered:

```
    Dim rst as DAO.Recordset  
    Dim sSql as String  
    Dim myValue as String  
    ssql = "select * from [HEADER]"  
    Set rst = currentdb.openrecordset(ssql)  
    with rst  
    .movelast  
    myValue = !TO  
    .addNew  
    .edit  
    !FROM = myValue  
    .update  
    end with  
    rst.close  
    set rst = nothing
```

It's not working yet.  I know it's probably something I've neglected.  I've never done anything like this before.  I think I do need to use your last scenario as I don't want the From and To to be the same in the form, I will need for the From to come from the prior row's To.  Any suggestions for what error I've made?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to look at putting some code in the 'to' field's 'after update' event.

In this procedure, let's say for example your 'to' field is called txtTo and your from field is called txtFrom you would do something like;

```
me.txtFrom.value = me.txtTo.value
me.txtFrom.refresh
```

If you txtFrom and txtTo are in a subform you would have to reference the fields like;

```
MainForm!subform!txtFrom.Value = MainForm!subForm!txtTo.value
```

If however you are calling these from a table and not unbound text boxes it's a bit more complicated, you'd need to open record set, add a new one and then write the value of the last to to the new from (from the top of my head) something like;

```
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset
Dim sSql as String
Dim myValue as String
ssql = "select * from [your table]"
Set rst = currentdb.openrecordset(ssql)
  with rst
    .movelast
      myValue = !ToFieldNameHere
        .addNew
          .edit
            !fromFieldNameHere = myValue
          .update
  end with
rst.close
set rst = nothing
```

then refresh the relevant controls (so in your case the text boxes), again you'd put this in the after update event of the To form if it's bound to a table.

Let me know how you get on!

Answer (score 0):

I think I made this out to be more difficult that it needed.  I found the solution to my issue.  For anyone else reading this my solution was to enter the "Default Value" of the field to:
 =DLast("field","table")
This auto-populates the field by default to the last field of my choice (in this case a different field than the one auto-populating).
I'm too new to this to know how to use the code suggested above properly but I do appreciate the time you took to respond.

Cheers